# xmemory0 Error When Trying to Build Project

Tags: c++, debugging, build, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing some additional options for a game (which means I don't have knowledge about whole game's methods, classes etc.).

Anyway, I have been trying to build the project for codes I've developed to test them. I've encountered some DirectX, Windows SDK Version, Compiler problems but managed to solve them.

I've downloaded source codes through SVN, so whole project is actually working. I just couldn't manage to build it in my local laptop or desktop computer.

This time I'm getting `xmemory0` error:

> Code: C2280
>
> Description: 'std::pair::pair(const std::pair &)':
>   attempting to reference a deleted function File: xmemory0 Line:840

Code part of the error is:

```
// xmemory0 internal header (from <memory>)
#pragma once
#ifndef _XMEMORY0_
#define _XMEMORY0_
#ifndef RC_INVOKED
#include <cstdint>  /* for uintptr_t */
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
#include <new>
#include <xutility>

 #pragma pack(push,_CRT_PACKING)
 #pragma warning(push,_STL_WARNING_LEVEL)
 #pragma warning(disable: _STL_DISABLED_WARNINGS)
 #pragma push_macro("new")
 #undef new
... // other code lines
template<class _Objty,
    class... _Types>
    void construct(_Objty *_Ptr, _Types&&... _Args)
    {   // construct _Objty(_Types...) at _Ptr
    ::new ((void *)_Ptr) _Objty(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...); // HERE IS GETTING ERROR
    }
... // other code lines
```

Comment: The error is *not* in the system header file, it's something in your code. Please edit your question to include the *full* and *complete* error, without any editing, perhaps even copy-paste the full build-log. Also try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the error, and show us.

Comment: It's a game project actually and couldn't write down the whole code, its 1272 lines and copyrighted and have tens of classes. Thanks anyway